# Glassfish 2.1 EJB 3.0 XML Service reference C# issue

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I come from the java world, I'm starting with C # and it's been a week since I can not solve this problem. I use an application server (glassfish 2.1) to provide data to a desktop application in C #, I use an EJB that sends data in XML format. This EJB is also consumed by various applications in Java desktop and works very well. The problem I have with C # is when the response (XML) of the EJB call is very large. I get a message the maximum string content length quota 8192 has been exceeded. This quota can be increased by changing the maxStringContentLength property in the xmldictionaryreaderquotas object that is used to create the XML reader. This only append wen i use the C# application in other computers so i try this

```
XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
            quotas.MaxStringContentLength = 1000000;
```

but is not the solution.

This is my app.config File (is created automatically when I add the reference to the WSDL )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="EjbFacturadorNetPortBinding" >
          <transactionFlow transactionProtocol="WSAtomicTransactionOctober2004" />
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />

<!-----------------I ADD THIS-------------------->
          <httpTransport  maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                          maxBufferSize="20000000"
                          maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          </httpTransport>
<!----------------------------------------------------->
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/EjbFacturadorNetService/EjbFacturadorNet"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="EjbFacturadorNetPortBinding"
          contract="WsFacturador.EjbFacturadorNet" name="EjbFacturadorNetPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is where i call EJB

```
      XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        quotas.MaxStringContentLength = 1000000;

        rta = wsFacturador.getTipoComprobantes();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(rta);


        var mainItems = (from key in doc.Descendants("comprobante")
                         select new ComboboxItem()
                         {
                             Text = key.Element("nombre").Value,
                             Value = key.Element("idComprobante").Value
                         }).ToList();
        cmbTipoComprobante.DataSource = mainItems.ToList();
```

Comment: Does the error occur in the WCF layer or when parsing the XML response ?

Comment: Hi, It happens when parsing the XML response

Comment: Thank you @Arnaud  for your interest in my problem, in the end it was so simple .. as always, I knew that I had to add the tag <readerQuotas/> somewhere, I tried to add it in <customBinding> without success. Just change the configuration of the client and stay this way

`<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMobileUtilities">          
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10000000"  />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>`

Comment: Yep, that's what I have suspected also but CustomBinding does not support the ReadQuotas property. Great to hear that you can use a simple bacicHttpBinding for communication with your service.